# Ruby App works with webrick but not with passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a ruby app to a server running Ubuntu -> Nginx -> Passenger.

I can access the site fine using 'rails s'  however passenger keeps returning the bellow error into the nginx log.  I've checked that rake 12.0.0 is installed and also tried setting up a new rails project to check if passenger would provide the "your on rails" page. But that doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried googleing and performing various bundle updates and gem installs.

```
  Error ID: a06f05a9
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-EVNeAF.html
  Message from application: <p>It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:</p>

  <pre class="commands">bundle install</pre>

<p>If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:</p>

<ol>
  <li>Is this app supposed to be run as the <code>dmn</code> user?</li>
  <li>Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
      see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.</li>
  <li>Please check whether the correct RVM gemset is being used.</li>
  <li>Sometimes, RVM gemsets may be broken.
      <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets">Try resetting them.</a></li>
</ol>

<p>-------- The exception is as follows: -------</p>
Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
<pre>  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require&#39;
  /home/dmn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler&#39;
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `&lt;module:App&gt;&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `&lt;module:PhusionPassenger&gt;&#39;
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `&lt;main&gt;&#39;</pre>"
```

Comment: You forgot to add the error.

Comment: Yup long day at work fat fingers pressed enter key too early. Updated Question.

Comment: What's your `passenger_ruby` set to? Also the error output should include a line like `Error details saved to: /var/folders/0x/gvllgn/T/passenger-error-N434xB.html` in which more detailed info is available.

Comment: passenger_ruby /home/dmn/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.3/ruby;

There is it contains the information in the original post along with system information, would you like a copy?

Comment: That would be helpful.

Comment: What's the best way to upload the html file?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add the information here so I've uploaded the HTML file here:
http://wjwb.uk/passenger-error-EVNeAF.html

Comment: Can you confirm that rake 1.12.0 is present in either `/home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3` or `/home/dmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global`?

Comment: rake 1.12.0 isn't present in either folder I cant use gem install to install it either, the current version of rake installed is 12.0.0.
I can't find rake 1.12.0 in the gemfile for the app either so I'm a bit lost as to why it needs it and how to install it if that's the cause of the issue?

Comment: I meant rake 12.0.0.

Comment: Rake 12.0.0 isn't in there the @global folder is missing. Rake 12.0.0 is in home/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/cache

Comment: What does the following command tell you if you run it from inside your app's directory? passenger-config about ruby-command

Comment: passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /usr/bin/ruby2.3
  Version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3

The following Ruby interpreter was found first in $PATH:
  Command: /usr/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby

I've tried using both of the above paths in the passenger-conf file

Comment: That indicates that your shell that you ran the command from hasn't sourced rvm (neither of those rubys appear to be rvm wrappers). You need to follow the rvm setup process so that you can get the correct config advice. Check if your user is part of the rvm group, and if so logout and then log back in in a fresh shell session. Also note that if you use a terminal multiplexor like gnu screen or tmux or similar, then you will have a hard time and need to take extra steps to get rvm working.

Comment: Hi Camden, thanks for the pointer, I've just got the app working. Started again with Centos7. Thanks.